# Cannot fit all my pictures horizontally with a border, one keeps getting pushed down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am fairly new and am running into a spacing problem. I have 4 pictures I would like in a row with a small border and aligned text underneath. However, when I alter any border or margin element, it pushes my last picture down, even when I have adjusted the widths of my other pictures. I believe it has something to do with the columns in bootstrap but am too new to understand how or what is happening. Any help would be appreciated! Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://www.goway.com/media/cache/fd/ac/fdaccd60e655c973c2b1855733512a02.jpg" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit South America!</p></a></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit Europe!</p></a></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://www.princess.com/images/learn/cruise-destinations/asia-cruises/southeast-asia/se-asia-unique-experiences.jpg" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit Asia!</p></a></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://news-events.sleeping-out.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/africa-sunset-wallpaper-1920x1200-379-kb.jpg" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit Africa!</p></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
.bottombanner {
width: 248px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
height: 150px;
display: inline-block;
}

.caption {
text-align: center;
background: #666;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0px 14px 0px 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.img-thumbnail {
margin: 1px;
}
```

If I remove the .img-thumbnail margin the pics all go to one row, but have to border between them and are smushed!

Also, does anyone have any tips for searching for questions better? I'm very new to programming and I feel like I have a hard time even wording what I want to ask in order to find solutions. Thanks guys!

Comment: check answer may be it will help you..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may reset `width` on `.img-thumbnail` to `auto` if you want to keep the `margin:1px`on `.img-thumbnail`.

Snippet below with your CSS and bootsrap3 library require the use of `!important`.

```
.img-thumbnail {
  margin: 1px;
  width: auto!important;   /* reset added */
}
```

```css
.bottombanner {
  width: 248px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
  background: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 14px 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  margin: 1px;
  width: auto!important;   /* reset added */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://www.goway.com/media/cache/fd/ac/fdaccd60e655c973c2b1855733512a02.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit South America!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit Europe!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://www.princess.com/images/learn/cruise-destinations/asia-cruises/southeast-asia/se-asia-unique-experiences.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit Asia!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://news-events.sleeping-out.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/africa-sunset-wallpaper-1920x1200-379-kb.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit Africa!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Best is to avoid the `!important` rule and search in your CSS file the previous rule to override. Here the margin:1px grows at least 2px wider each of your box ... pushing the last one down.

---

Another way could be to fake that 1px margin drawing borders via inset shadow :
see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

> The box-shadow CSS property describes one or more shadow effects as a comma-separated list.

```
.img-thumbnail {
  /* margin: 1px; removed */
    border:none;/* remove borders */
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px white, inset 0 0 0 2px gray;/* fake borders */
}
```

```css
.bottombanner {
  width: 248px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
  background: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 14px 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  /* margin: 1px; removed */
    border:none;/* remove borders */
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px white, inset 0 0 0 2px gray;/* fake borders */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://www.goway.com/media/cache/fd/ac/fdaccd60e655c973c2b1855733512a02.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit South America!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit Europe!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://www.princess.com/images/learn/cruise-destinations/asia-cruises/southeast-asia/se-asia-unique-experiences.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit Asia!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://news-events.sleeping-out.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/africa-sunset-wallpaper-1920x1200-379-kb.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit Africa!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

3rd option is to use [boostrap4](http://bootstrap4.guide/) and add a flex class

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex"><!-- boostrap class that uses the flexmodel -->
          <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail">
```

```css
.bottombanner {
  width: 248px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.caption {
  text-align: center;
  background: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 14px 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex"><!-- boostrap class that uses the flexmodel -->
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://www.goway.com/media/cache/fd/ac/fdaccd60e655c973c2b1855733512a02.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit South America!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit Europe!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://www.princess.com/images/learn/cruise-destinations/asia-cruises/southeast-asia/se-asia-unique-experiences.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit Asia!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://news-events.sleeping-out.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/africa-sunset-wallpaper-1920x1200-379-kb.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#">
          <p class="caption">Visit Africa!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful and I actually like the look of your second solution even better! What are the four values for box shadow? I would assume up left down right, but the border shadow goes all the way around anyway, so I'm not sure, and why do you have it listed twice, separated by a comma?

Comment: @jl7897 the comma lets you add as many shadows needed. the first one is white to fake the 1px margin , the second (2px) is dark partially hidden from the first shadow  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow for explanation in proper english ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the div below the .row and put the img-thumbnail inside the img tag.

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div><!-- remove this div tag -->
                <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://www.goway.com/media/cache/fd/ac/fdaccd60e655c973c2b1855733512a02.jpg" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit South America!</p></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit Europe!</p></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://www.princess.com/images/learn/cruise-destinations/asia-cruises/southeast-asia/se-asia-unique-experiences.jpg" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit Asia!</p></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://news-events.sleeping-out.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/africa-sunset-wallpaper-1920x1200-379-kb.jpg" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit Africa!</p></a></div>
            </div><!-- remove this div tag -->
        </div>
      </div>
```

Final result below:

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-sm-3"><img class=" img-thumbnail bottombanner" src="https://www.goway.com/media/cache/fd/ac/fdaccd60e655c973c2b1855733512a02.jpg" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit South America!</p></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><img class=" img-thumbnail bottombanner" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit Europe!</p></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><img class=" img-thumbnail bottombanner" src="http://www.princess.com/images/learn/cruise-destinations/asia-cruises/southeast-asia/se-asia-unique-experiences.jpg" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit Asia!</p></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><img class=" img-thumbnail bottombanner" src="http://news-events.sleeping-out.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/africa-sunset-wallpaper-1920x1200-379-kb.jpg" alt=""><a href="#"><p class="caption">Visit Africa!</p></a></div> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to move the images into their own div's like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://www.goway.com/media/cache/fd/ac/fdaccd60e655c973c2b1855733512a02.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="#">
      <p class="caption">Visit South America!</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt="">
    <a href="#">
      <p class="caption">Visit Europe!</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://www.princess.com/images/learn/cruise-destinations/asia-cruises/southeast-asia/se-asia-unique-experiences.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="#">
      <p class="caption">Visit Asia!</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="img-thumbnail"><img class="bottombanner" src="http://news-events.sleeping-out.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/africa-sunset-wallpaper-1920x1200-379-kb.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="#">
      <p class="caption">Visit Africa!</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This approach decouples the images from the columns (the classes titled 'col-sm-3'). In this way, the images can now "fill" the columns.

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/pwqrxx).

Comment: Hey thanks so much, this worked beautifully! Do you know the reasoning behind why it wasn't working before?

Comment: hard to explain but i'll try - the columns have a set width that's exact. 'blending' the image and column together and adding a 1px margin causes the overflow / wrap affect, as the columns are now too wide for their container. placing the images inside divs now means the image will expand to the width of the inner dimension of the column (rather than the outer dimension of the column)

Answer (score 0):

The margin property you have added on `.img-thumbnail` is interfering with the columns being on same row.
This is because the `box-sizing: border-box` property which the bootstrap applies to its **columns** and **rows** doesn't count the margin of the box but only **paddding**, **border** and **content**.
So you have following solutions to this problem-

1. Simply remove `margin: 1px` from `.img-thumbnail`.

   **OR**
2. Override the default width of the `.col-sm-3` as demonstrated.

i.e.

```
.col-sm-3 {
    width: calc(25% - 2px) !important;
}
```

> This should solve your problem. You can change the `2px` to whatever
>   your border is times 2 **(border-width * 2)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
i think  this may help for you , i updated your code by using the bootstrap 
classes,
<style>
    .thumbnail img
     {
       width: 100%;
       height: 180px !important;
     }

    .bottom-text {
       text-align: center;
       background: #000 !important;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: white;
       max-width: 100%;
       margin-top: 1px;
      /*margin: 0px 14px 0px 10px;*/
      }
      .bottom-text a
        {
         color: #fff;
        }
      .bottom-text a:hover
      {
        color: #eee;
         text-decoration: none;
       }
</style>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="bottombanner" src="https://www.goway.com/media/cache/fd/ac/fdaccd60e655c973c2b1855733512a02.jpg"  alt="">
                        <div class="caption bottom-text">
                            <a href="#">Visit South America!</a>
                        </div>    
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="bottombanner" src="https://i.gocollette.com/img/destination-page/europe/europe-continent/europe-ms2.jpg?h=720&w=1280&la=en" alt="">
                        <div class="caption bottom-text">
                            <a href="#">Visit Europe!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>        
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="bottombanner" src="http://www.princess.com/images/learn/cruise-destinations/asia-cruises/southeast-asia/se-asia-unique-experiences.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="caption bottom-text">
                            <a href="#">Visit Asia!</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="bottombanner" src="http://news-events.sleeping-out.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/africa-sunset-wallpaper-1920x1200-379-kb.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="caption bottom-text">
                            <a href="#">Visit Africa!</a>
                        </div>  
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```